# Turning on a Wifi Hotspot in an Android App Automatically

Tags: java, android, wifi, hotspot

I have an android program, written in Java and it uses a Wifi Hotspot, which at the minute I am having to turn on and give the settings manually.

I would like for the hotspot to be turned on with my settings from inside the program.

I have seen a few posts relating to this, some people with answers but they don't seem to be very clear.

Does anyone know of anything that can help me?

Comment: Look folks, there are 3rd party apps existing which you can use to turn on the wifi hotspot such as this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wifi.hotspot&hl=en If they can do it, so can you. Don't accept too quickly the answer that it can't be done.

Comment: I hear what you're saying but if there is a way it's a very closely guarded secret which no one on here seems to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know there' absolutely no API on Android to achieve this functionality.
The maximum you can do is like on this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.budius.WiFiShoot that it checks if the feature is enabled, and in case it's not it sends the user to the settings screen.

Comment: Thanks. I feared that would be the case but I thought I'd see if the wider community had any bright spark ideas. My boss wasn't very happy when I said it couldn't be done, but if it can't be done, it can't be done.

Comment: my post clearly specifies "as far as I know"; there's absolutely no reason to be rude like this.

Comment: hey @PippaRoseSmith , that was not directed to you. The person who posted the rude comment deleted it. It's probably the same person who down voted it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this way:

- Scan all avaiable wifi hotspot.
- Check security type of these hotspots(WPA, WPA2, WEP, OPEN).
- Make authenticate to connect hotspot by SSID.

I used [wifi-connector](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-connecter/) library (especially [Wifi.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-connecter/source/browse/src/com/farproc/wifi/connecter/Wifi.java) file)

Comment: I want to create the hotspot, not scan for available ones. Thanks anyway though, the code you posted is really interesting.